# How to drop rows in R with almost the same column value?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataset with a column of names. I would like to drop rows with the lesser "P" value, if there exists one with a higher value. For example, in the dataset below, I would like to drop the row ID's 3 and 5 since there exists a 'Texas P5' and a 'North Dakota P9.' What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

| ID | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Minnesota P2 | 342 |
| 2 | Vermont P7 | 342 |
| 3 | Texas P4 | 65 |
| 4 | New Mexico | 643 |
| 5 | North Dakota P8 | 78 |
| 6 | North Dakota P9 | 245 |
| 7 | Texas P5 | 856 |
| 8 | Minnesota LP | 342 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R way. Use `ave` to split the data by `Name` excluding the numbers, and check which group element is equal to its greatest element. `ave` returns a vector of the same class as its input, in this case character. So coerce to logical and subset the original data frame.

```r
x<-"
ID  Name    Score
1   'Minnesota P2'  342
2   'Vermont P7'    342
3   'Texas P4'  65
4   'New Mexico'    643
5   'North Dakota P8'   78
6   'North Dakota P9'   245
7   'Texas P5'  856
8   'Minnesota LP'  342"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)


i <- with(df1, ave(Name, sub("\\d+", "", Name), FUN = \(x){
  x == tail(sort(x), 1)
}))
df1[as.logical(i),]
#>   ID            Name Score
#> 1  1    Minnesota P2   342
#> 2  2      Vermont P7   342
#> 4  4      New Mexico   643
#> 6  6 North Dakota P9   245
#> 7  7        Texas P5   856
#> 8  8    Minnesota LP   342
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, which presupposes that the `Name` parts by which the `Name`values differ are always 2 characters long, preceded by whitespace, and positioned at the end of the string:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # create a dummy var without the variable part in `Name`:
  mutate(Names_dum = sub("\\s.{2}$","",Name)) %>%
  # for each `Names_dum`...:
  group_by(Names_dum) %>%
  # now filter for the maximum value:
  filter(Score == max(Score)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # remove the dummy:
  select(-Names_dum)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Name            Score
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 Minnesota P2      342
2 Vermont P7        342
3 New Mexico        643
4 North Dakota P9   245
5 Texas P5          856
6 Minnesota LP      342
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Minnesota P2","Vermont P7", "Texas P4", "New Mexico", "North Dakota P8", "North Dakota P9", "Texas P5", "Minnesota LP"), 
                 Score = c(342,342,65,643,78,245,856,342))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base option:

```r
dat <- cbind(dat, strcapture("(.*[^ ]) *P([0-9]+)$", dat$Name, list(Name2 = "", P = 0L)))
isna <- is.na(dat$P)
dat$P[isna] <- 0L; dat$Name2[isna] <- dat$Name[isna]
dat
#   ID            Name Score        Name2 P
# 1  1    Minnesota P2   342    Minnesota 2
# 2  2      Vermont P7   342      Vermont 7
# 3  3        Texas P4    65        Texas 4
# 4  4      New Mexico   643   New Mexico 0
# 5  5 North Dakota P8    78 North Dakota 8
# 6  6 North Dakota P9   245 North Dakota 9
# 7  7        Texas P5   856        Texas 5
# 8  8    Minnesota LP   342 Minnesota LP 0

dat[ave(dat$P, dat$Name2, FUN = function(z) seq_along(z) == which.max(z)) > 0,]
#   ID            Name Score        Name2 P
# 1  1    Minnesota P2   342    Minnesota 2
# 2  2      Vermont P7   342      Vermont 7
# 4  4      New Mexico   643   New Mexico 0
# 6  6 North Dakota P9   245 North Dakota 9
# 7  7        Texas P5   856        Texas 5
# 8  8    Minnesota LP   342 Minnesota LP 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `data.table` approach:

```r
library(data.table)

dt[, Score1 := max(Score), .(gsub(" [A-Z0-9]+$", "", Name))][
  Score >= Score1, .(Name, Score)]

#>               Name Score
#> 1:    Minnesota P2   342
#> 2:      Vermont P7   342
#> 3:      New Mexico   643
#> 4: North Dakota P9   245
#> 5:        Texas P5   856
#> 6:    Minnesota LP   342
```